# How to determine the current case in a switch statement?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Is is possible to determine which case is currently being evaluated? Something like this example code:

```
const int one = 1;
const int two = 2;

int current_num = 1;

switch (current_num){
       case one:
       case two:
           WriteLine(current_case) //outputs 'one'
           break;
}
```

I believe I could get tricky and use a dictionary or something to look up the `current_num` once I've begun to `WriteLine`, but there could be a built-in way to get the name of the current case currently being evaluated.

*edit*: Short answer, it's not possible. Check out JonSkeet's answer for a plausible alternative.

Comment: That isn't valid C# to start with, as `case` expressions can only be constants. I think you're trying to do something which really doesn't exist...

Comment: @JonSkeet: true, but if you replace the "one" with 1 etc, it's still an interesting question imho. Though I highly doubt it's possible without some IL Weaving or other post-processing technique.

Comment: @Alxandr: If you replace "one" with 1, then why not just use `WriteLine(current_num)`? It's really not clear what the OP is trying to achieve - I've posted an answer which *may* help, but we could really do with more clarity.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Stupid me, I didn't think that you could just output the variable you are switching over -.- . Now I just feel stupid :p, but I still think it's interesting trying to figure out (runtime) which path was used to get here (given that you can't simply use a StackTrace, because it's not functions). But in this case that's probably off-topic.

Comment: @TankorSmash: What do you mean by "look up the current_num once I've begun to WriteLine"? If you just want the value of `current_num`, just write that out...

Comment: @JonSkeet Edited OP to make it valid C# code. I was trying to simplify the code as much as I could, and may have gone overboard. I've got a for loop that iterates over all the items in the database, about 200k and for the sake of saving time writing code (maybe 2 minutes of time saved, tops) I wanted to `Trace.WriteLine("saving at current checkpoint")` for the current switch case, which serves as a checkpoint of sorts to save the changes to the db. So `one` is really `25049`, and `two` is `55023`. I suppose that the original question's answer is 'not possible', thanks.

Comment: @TankorSmash: So what do you actually want to output? If it's basically a mapping from number to string, then either use a `Dictionary<int, string>` or use the enum approach I've suggested in my answer.

Comment: I'm looking to output the case name. `one` or `two` here, something similar to `System.Reflection`'s `GetField`, like  say `GetCase`. But if that's not possible, your answer is very helpful otherwise.

Comment: Just an idea, but if you want the two different cases to yield different results, you could consider to use two separate cases with their own code, possibly refactoring the shared code into a method that you call from both cases after doing specific stuff.

Comment: @lesderid Yeah that's a good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but I *suspect* you'd be better off with an enum:

```
enum Foo {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3
}

...

int someValue = 2;
Foo foo = (Foo) someValue;
Console.WriteLine(foo); // Two
```

You can still use this within a case statement:

```
switch (foo) {
    case Foo.One:
    case Foo.Two:
        Console.WriteLine(foo); // One or Two, depending on foo
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Not One or Two");
}
```

Comment: think is about getting all case instances of the current break scope; returning a array of [One,Two];

Comment: @H3sDW11e: Well the answer was accepted (over 9 years ago), so presumably it satisfied the OP...